# How can I assign a number to X, if X is in a range of numbers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am working with random and what I want is that if, (for example) X = 173. X must be 10.
Let me explain: depending on a range of numbers, X will have a new value:

if X is less than or equal to 10, X must be equal to 26
if X is less than or equal to 20, X must be equal to 35,
if X is less than or equal to 30, X must be equal to 12...

Every 10 units X will have a different value
So far this is what I have, but I don't think this code is the most appropriate:

```
var X = 55;

if(X <= 10){
  X = 26;
}else if (X<=20){
  X = 35;
}else if (X <= 30){
  X = 12;
}else if(X <= 40){
  X = 28;
}else if (X <= 50 ) {
  X = 7;
}else if (X <= 60) {
  X = 29
}

console.log(X);
```

The problem is that if you continue like this, it should do 36 validations (if)
I'm working with vanilla JS

Comment: Sounds like the job for a simple look-up table and not a pile of `if` statements. Consider: `lookup[Math.floor(x / 10)]`

Comment: Is is that, you want to assign a fixed random value to X on each condition?

Comment: Yes ... I'm doing a casino type of game (for a school assignment),
so every time you click a button, x takes a random value and that value corresponds to some numbers in an image ... that's why x takes a value that has nothing to do with its previous value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come to think of it, you can do this without any looping at all, still assuming the ranges you provided.

*Thanks to @TedHopp for my math error fix!*

```js
const values = [26, 35, 12, 28, 7, 29];

var x = 55;

x = x ? (values[Math.ceil(x/10)-1] || x) : values[0];

console.log(x);
```

---

***original answer***

Assuming you actually have ranges of 10, you can use a single array of the potentially assigned values, and iterate the array until you find the range you want.

Like this:

```js
const values = [26, 35, 12, 28, 7, 29];

var x = 55;

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (x <= ((i + 1) * 10)) {
    x = values[i];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(x);
```

Or you can use `.find()` for this to be a little more succinct.

```js
const values = [26, 35, 12, 28, 7, 29];

var x = 55;

x = values.find((_, i) => x <= ((i + 1) * 10)) || x

console.log(x);
```

Comment: You probably don't want `Math.floor(x/10)` as the index, because that would treat 9 and 10 differently, not what OP wants. You could use `Math.floor((x-1)/10)` or `Math.ceil(x/10)-1`.

Comment: @TedHopp: You're right. I just realized that they were all wrong that way. Corrected the last two already. I'll update with your solution.

Comment: Actually, if `x` is `0`, we still have trouble. The first range is one larger than the rest. I'll special case that value.

Comment: You're welcome. You can usually do it mathematically any time you have ranges that remain consistent in some way.